# How to wrap text in link?

Tags: text, netbeans, hyperlink, word-wrap, emmet

I want to wrap a simple link text in a way like this:

`http://google.de` & rarr; `<a href="http://google.de">http://google.de</a>`

I marked the link and wrote this zen code ([emmet](/questions/tagged/emmet)):

```
a[href=*]*
```

But the `href` attribute of the link is not set correctly

```
<a href="*">http://google.de</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about `*` usage?

> http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/Actions

It doesn't seems it's used for what you want.